# How to know at which line the error is during hardhat test

Tags: solidity, javascript, erc-721, hardhat

I am following a tutorial for a real estate web3.0 project. I am doing the exact same thing as he is but I don't know why I am still getting an error.

This is my contract Escrow.sol

```
contract Escrow {
address public nftAddress;
address payable public seller;
address public inspector;
address public lender;

mapping(uint256 => bool) public isListed;
mapping(uint256 => uint256) public purchasePrice;
mapping(uint256 => uint256) public escrowAmount;
mapping(uint256 => address) public buyer;

constructor(
    address _nftAddress,
    address payable _seller,
    address _inspector,
    address _lender
) {
    nftAddress = _nftAddress;
    seller = _seller;
    inspector = _inspector;
    lender = _lender;
}

function list(
    uint256 _nftID,
    uint256 _purchasePrice,
    uint256 _escrowAmount,
    address _buyer
) public {
    // transfer NFTs from seller to this contract
    IERC721(nftAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _nftID);

    isListed[_nftID] = true;
    purchasePrice[_nftID] = _purchasePrice;
    escrowAmount[_nftID] = _escrowAmount;
    buyer[_nftID] = _buyer;
}
```

}

And I am testing it like this

```
 const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const tokens = (n) => {
  return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), "ether");
};

describe("Escrow", () => {
  let buyer, seller, inspector, lender;
  let realEstate, escrow;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // setup Accounts
    [buyer, seller, inspector, lender] = await ethers.getSigners();

    //Deploying Real Estate contract
    const RealEstate = await ethers.getContractFactory("RealEstate");
    realEstate = await RealEstate.deploy();

    //Mint
    let transaction = await realEstate
      .connect(seller)
      .mint(
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQVcpsjrA6cr1iJjZAodYwmPekYgbnXGo4DFubJiLc2EB/1.json"
      );
    await transaction.wait();

   

 const Escrow = await ethers.getContractFactory("Escrow");
    escrow = await Escrow.deploy(
      realEstate.address,
      seller.address,
      inspector.address,
      lender.address
    );

    //Approve property
    transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).approve(escrow.address, 1);
    await transaction.wait();

    //List property
    transaction = await escrow
      .connect(seller)
      .list(1, buyer.address, tokens(10), tokens(5));
    await transaction.wait();
  });

 

  describe("Listing", () => {
    it("Updates as listed", async () => {
      const result = await escrow.isListed(1);
      expect(result).to.be.equal(true);
    });

    it("Returns buyer", async () => {
      const result = await escrow.buyer(1);
      expect(result).to.be.equal(buyer.address);
    });

    it("Returns Purchase Price", async () => {
      const result = await escrow.purchasePrice(1);
      expect(result).to.be.equal(tokens(10));
    });

    it("Returns escrow Amount", async () => {
      const result = await escrow.escrowAmount(1);
      expect(result).to.be.equal(tokens(5));
    });

    it("Updates Ownership", async () => {
      expect(await realEstate.ownerOf(1)).to.be.equal(escrow.address);
    });
  });
});
```

But after using `npx hardhat test` I get the Error

```
 1) Escrow
   "before each" hook for "Updates as listed":
 Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value={"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x4563918244f40000"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

I can't find at which line the error is, although I have checked everything from his GitHub repo and everything is the same. If you guys can tell me how to find where the error is and how to solve it

Comment: It worked now, I just copy pasted the list function from GitHub and it was the same as the function I wrote but it now worked.

Comment: Debugging is difficult when you're using other language to test Solidity code. Consider using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/).

Comment: That error means the problem is in the before or beforeEach. From the error message an address parameter is receiving something that doesn't look like an address "0x4563918244f40000". Perhaps you are missing some double quotes surrounding an address.

Answer (score 0):

In the contract, following function's first 3 params are `uint256` and last one is `address`

```
function list(
    uint256 _nftID,
    uint256 _purchasePrice,
    uint256 _escrowAmount,
    address _buyer
)
```

Have a look at code snippet you are using in beforeEach

```
//List property
 transaction = await escrow
   .connect(seller)
   .list(1, buyer.address, tokens(10), tokens(5));
```

Here you are passing `address` in 2nd argument and `uint256` in 4th argument that is creating the issue. Just swap the positions of these arguments and it should work then.

Comment: This is not answering the question, but fixing the problem. The question was about the line number.